# Lost restriction passcode

Tags: ios, password

I have forgotten both my iTunes backup password and my iPhone's restriction passcode. How can I recover my restriction passcode without wiping my iPhone?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Answer (score 1):

The only REAL way to  recover the passcode is to factory reset your iPhone. There's no way to recover it and find the code unless you remember it. If you would like to confirm what I'm saying is true, I suggest contacting apple support.

But yeaaa... The only way is to do a factory reset on your iPhone and create a new passcode

Theres plenty of guides online on how to reset your phone!